# Create Object in Liferay Web Content Template

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-velocity

I am trying to instantiate MimeMessage class using Liferay WebContent Velocity template and having difficulty with it. Here is my code

```
    #set ($properties = $portal.getClass().forName("java.util.Properties").newInstance())

#set ($VOID = $properties.put("mail.smtp.host","10.175.150.156"))
#set ($VOID = $properties.put("mail.smtp.host","25"))

#set ($mailSession = $portal.getClass().forName("javax.mail.Session").getInstance($properties, null))

Mail Session: $mailSession <br/>

#set ($mimeMessage = $portal.getClass().forName("javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage").newInstance($mailSession))

MimeMessage : $mimeMessage <br/>
```

Here $mimeMessage is not getting instantiated. Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using? What is your configuration? Especially, do you have any setting for the runtime.introspector.uberspect configuration key? What are the outputs of intermediary calls like $portal.getClass() or $portal.getClass().forName("javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage") ?